# Why is my Material Nodes -based blender internal texture not translucent like the other one? How do I work around it?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to animate a neon sign that blinks, but I'm having trouble with my materials.  [Here's the .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28445)

I am using the Blender Internal renderer.  In order to have a neon sign that blinks I created a material that uses nodes to alternate between two simple materials.

[image: material nodes]

The "Fac" property on the mixes is animated using constant interpolation so it toggles between 0 and 1.

One of the materials (neon phase 2) works just fine.  Unfortunately, neon phase 1 (which is the "opposite") does not.  When it is off it is not translucent like glass.  It is a shiny opaque grey.

What is the critical difference between the two node-based materials that makes one work correctly, and the other be opaque all the time?  How do I fix it or work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Vailreth from IRC.  He noticed that the Transparency under Render Pipeline Options (which started out minimized) was not checked on the problem material:

[image]